# How to secure APIs for Registration and Login in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I have been and nowadays may be almost every Django Framework users using Django Rest Framework for creating REST APIs. I am using it with token authentication using [django-rest-framework-jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt) and it returns the token when User logged in through our rest API.

So the question is how to secure any registration or login views for our API endpoints.Any high-level XSS scripts can have malicious looping for creating registrations.How can we secure it in Django Rest Framework ?

Comment: Doing this at application level is not the best solution. Ideally you should use something like fail2ban to detect known attack patterns and block them at firewall level. That way the brute force attempt doesn't get as far as the application once detected.

Comment: @MatthewDaly yes, I looked for the fail2ban. But the current solution I found that Mobile and Backend developer can share the one secret key. So in those APIs mobile app will send some encryption key based on some text, and backend developer can decrypt text using the same text.

Comment: @Aniket I'm talking about alongside the JWT implementation. If someone is trying to brute-force the registration or authentication endpoint, you want to stop them getting as far as the application, because even if they fail to authenticate, the overhead from multiple requests can kill the application. Fail2ban will block the IP address when the log entries match a known pattern so they won't be able to even make a request.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you have stated, you cannot have an authentication system like JWT protect your pages like login and registration.
However there are many other things you can do. Below I have mentioned two of them briefly to get you started and rest you can study in detail.

- **First to address the XSS issue -**

Some browsers have the ability to block content that appears to be an XSS attack. They work by looking for JavaScript content in the GET or POST parameters of a page. If the JavaScript is replayed in the server’s response, the page is blocked from rendering and an error page is shown instead.
The X-XSS-Protection header is used to control the operation of the XSS filter.

**Implementation**

Django provides middleware and settings added in settings>base.py
Middleware:

```
django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware
```

Settings:

```
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
This sets header to X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Other things you can do to prevent some script from hitting your login or registration pages repeatedly is -

- **Brute Force Attack**

**Security Issue**

An automated programme may attack to hack username and password of a user or to slow down the server.

These attacks generally take one of a few forms:
1. One IP address trying one username with many passwords. 
2. Many IP addresses trying one username with many passwords. 
3. One IP address trying many usernames with a few common passwords. 
4. Many IP addresses trying many usernames with one or a few common passwords. 
5. Attacking on any random url on domain to slow down the server response.

**Implementation**

Django Rest Framework provides inbuilt settings for throttling

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.ScopedRateThrottle',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '60/minute',
        'app1': '10000/day',
        'app2': '10000/day',
    },
    ...
}
```

Another solution is django-defender or django-ratelimit for preventing only for failed login attempts.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution after customized Django REST Throttling,

Its Blocking particular user after 3 login attempts (Block user_id that presents in my application). Block IP address after 6 login attempts for anonymous user.

**prevent.py:-**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from collections import Counter

from rest_framework.throttling import SimpleRateThrottle
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserLoginRateThrottle(SimpleRateThrottle):
    scope = 'loginAttempts'

    def get_cache_key(self, request, view):
        user = User.objects.filter(username=request.data.get('username'))
        ident = user[0].pk if user else self.get_ident(request)

        return self.cache_format % {
            'scope': self.scope,
            'ident': ident
        }

    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        """
        Implement the check to see if the request should be throttled.
        On success calls `throttle_success`.
        On failure calls `throttle_failure`.
        """
        if self.rate is None:
            return True

        self.key = self.get_cache_key(request, view)
        if self.key is None:
            return True

        self.history = self.cache.get(self.key, [])
        self.now = self.timer()

        while self.history and self.history[-1] <= self.now - self.duration:
            self.history.pop()

        if len(self.history) >= self.num_requests:
            return self.throttle_failure()

        if len(self.history) >= 3:
            data = Counter(self.history)
            for key, value in data.items():
                if value == 2:
                    return self.throttle_failure()
        return self.throttle_success(request)

    def throttle_success(self, request):
        """
        Inserts the current request's timestamp along with the key
        into the cache.
        """
        user = User.objects.filter(username=request.data.get('username'))
        if user:
            self.history.insert(0, user[0].id)
        self.history.insert(0, self.now)
        self.cache.set(self.key, self.history, self.duration)
        return True
```

**view.py:-**

```
from .prevent import UserLoginRateThrottle
   ....
   ....
   ....
   class ObtainAuthToken(auth_views.ObtainAuthToken):
       throttle_classes = (UserLoginRateThrottle,)/use this method here your login view

       def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           ....
       ....
```

**settings.py:-**

```
# Django-rest-framework
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'loginAttempts': '6/hr',
        'user': '1000/min',
    }
}
```